# UploadString POST method not working in C#

Tags: c#, php

I have tried to solve my problem by many ways but no success except by switching to DownloadString and sending a GET method which i don't want to do.

So I'm simply trying to upload a string variable to a simple PHP script using WebClient.UploadString method but the PHP script can't receive the script for a reason that I ignore

Here is my C# code to upload the string variable

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string username = "John";
        
wc.UploadString("http://127.0.0.1/index/username.php", username);
```

And here is the PHP code to store the C# variable in $username var then in database

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if(isset($username) && $username != '')
{
    $sqlqueries;
}
```

Comment: Your entire data is just "John". So, when your php-backend receives the data, it looks for a field/key-value-pair named "username", but there is no such thing in the request data, there is just "John". Also pay attention to the official php documentation for the $_POST variable, especially what it says about how requests should be configured for the $_POST variable to work properly. Lastly, as a side note, the usage of WebClient in new projects is discouraged; instead it is recommended to use HttpClient.

Comment: For brevity sake, you just need to do this: `wc.UploadString("http://127.0.0.1/index/username.php", "username="+username);`  but you should really understand the format of data being passed to PHP and how it works first.

Comment: Does the connection complete or is the problem the transfer of the headers and body?  You are using HTTP (not HTTPS).  Many servers no longer accept HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem we just have to switch the UploadString method into UploadValues using System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection

The C# code should look like this :

```
var data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection { ["name"] = "John"};

WebClient wc = new WebClient();   
wc.UploadValues("http://127.0.0.1/index/username.php", data);
```

And the PHP code will still look the same :

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if(isset($username) && $username != '')
{
    $sqlqueries;
}
```